# Trying to CRTP. Why does this produce strange results?

Tags: c++

This is basic CRTP code.

When I run this code, the output is "world" and not "hello". Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Derived>
struct A {
    void foo()
    {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar();
    }
};

struct B : A<B>{
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct C : A<C> {
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << "world" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    void* b = new B();
    auto c = static_cast<A<C>*>(b);
    c->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using `gcc 5.4`.

The main problem is that `A<B>` and `A<C>` are different types. I would like to store them in a vector and use it like I would a polymorphic inheritance type with virtual functions. I was trying to see what `void*` storing would happen and I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: `A<B>` and `A<C>` are unrelated types, so `static_cast<A<C>*>(b)` is casting a pointer to another type it has no business being cast to.

Comment: What about to store pointers of base-type A in a vector then cast. "A vector is a container that holds elements of same type with a flexible size".

Comment: "*I would like to store them in a vector and use it like I would a polymorphic inheritance type with virtual functions.*" Then why are you using the CRTP? The CRTP is for when you *don't want* runtime polymorphism.

Comment: @NicolBolas I want to store them in a single `vector`. If they are different types, I guess its not possible.

Comment: @Raindrop7 Can't do `A*`. It requires a template parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> void* b = new B();
> auto c = static_cast<A<C>*>(b);
> c->foo();
> ```

This yields undefined behavior. You are accessing an object of type `B` through a pointer to an unrelated type `A<C>`. That violates strict aliasing.

If you want to store pointers to different object types in a vector, then you should be using regular old `virtual` functions and inheritance. The CRTP is for taking common functionality and applying it to different types. It's *not* for treating two distinct types the same.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need CRTP to see that there is something fishy in your example. Lets simplify it a lot:

```
#include <iostream>


struct B {
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct C {
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << "world" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    void* b = new B();
    auto c = static_cast<C*>(b);
    c->bar();
    return 0;
}
```

This prints `world`. We just called a `C` method on a `B` instance. How could this happen? Using `void*` allows you to bypass some rules, but the rules still exists. You shall not treat an instance as something it is not. If you do, you get undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

> The main problem is that `A<B>` and `A<C>` are different types. I would like to store them in a vector and use it like I would a polymorphic inheritance type with virtual functions.

You can do that by defining a regular class that can be the base class of the class template `A`.

```
struct Base 
{
    virtual ~Base{} {}
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template<typename Derived>
struct A : Base {
    void foo() override
    {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar();
    }
};
```

Now you can use:

```
std::vector<Base*> baseObjects;
baseObjects.push_back(new B());
baseObjects.push_back(new C());

baseObjects[0]->foo();
baseObjects[1]->foo();
```

Comment: I want to avoid all virtual functions. That's why I'm using CRTP.

Comment: @Mochan, that is a good goal. However, that prohibits you from storing pointers to objects of type `B` and `C` in a common container withoug using `void*`. If you use `void*` in a container, there is no way to figure out whether the underlying object is of type `B` or `C`. That's the downside of using a CRTP.